# dynamic taging node with keywords(terms) is body

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, nodes

I have some vocabulary and I want to tag the content automatically  with  keywords types in body of content.
Example my body is :
`"Drupal is lovely content management system that provide good api to developer"`

and
`Drupal`,`content management system` are in vocabulary1
`api`,`developer` are in vocabulary2

How can I extract my vocabulary tags auto from body of contents?

Comment: There is a Hashtags module (http://drupal.org/project/hashtags) that does this if you enter things like #drupal, so, while it doesn't do exactly what you want, it might be a good start for some custom coding on your behalf.

Comment: But it is more limitation , like cant tag 2 word(separated by space) terms

Comment: As mentioned, it might be a good start for some custom coding as the mechanics of adding taxonomy terms based upon text in the body are in that module.  So, with that already written, you could cycle through your various vocabularies and their terms looking for matches and then when found, creating links, applying the terms, etc, using already written code.  Just realize that natural language is pretty difficult to codify.  Eg, what do you do when you find `Drupal` and `Drupal Content Management System` and have both as terms and come across the `Drupal` term first.  Just lots to think about.

Comment: Give me few minutes to time travel. I'm sure I've done this before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching and pay time I found the great module [rule autotag](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=rule_tags%20drupal&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&ved=0CDkQFjAC&url=https://drupal.org/project/rules_autotag&ei=WjagUtKHHtHJsgaU_IHACA&usg=AFQjCNEFyrGpG_nD6R0bCbgOp-Xl3c5ozw&sig2=vcZul0ttTzqn9q8zcf8v5g&bvm=bv.57155469,d.Yms),it is great,of course it is not completely which I want but extract tag from body very good with good  performance

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by writing a custom module that analyzes the node content in a hook_node_presave hook and check if the terms from a particular vocabulary is present in the node.

I created a small custom module that just works if you enter the correct parameters. 
https://github.com/Ayesh/drupal-node-auto-tag

Download a tarball or clone it, and set the node type, field names and vocabulary ID in top of the .module and enable the module.

Good luck!

Comment: you tell analyzes node content, but you suppose that node have 5000 word,how you parse word? did you method efficient?

Comment: It doesn't really analyze the content to an algorithm. It just gets all words to an array, remove duplicates and gets the intersection of terms and words(both stemmed). If any, they will be added to the taxonomy field.